# How to implement stored procedure/function in postgresql version 12?

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

How I can implement it? I am confused in syntax also?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE Function dailyyyy_volation_routine(_ispeed_count integer,_rlvd_count integer,_stopline_count integer,_wrongdir_count integer
                                                     ,_wronglane_count integer,_zebracross_count integer,_total_count integer)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO temp_daily_stats(ispeed_count,rlvd_count,stopline_count,wrongdir_count,wronglane_count,zebracross_count,total_count)
with t1 as (SELECT SUM(ispeed_count) as ispeed_count from temp_hourly_stats),
t3 as (SELECT SUM(rlvd_count) as rlvd_count from temp_hourly_stats),
t4 as (SELECT SUM(stop_line_count) as stopline_count from temp_hourly_stats),
t5 as (SELECT SUM(wrong_dir_count) as wrong_dir_count from temp_hourly_stats),
t6 as (SELECT SUM(wrong_lane_count) as wrong_lane_count from temp_hourly_stats),
t7 as (SELECT SUM(zebra_cross_count) as zebra_cross_count from temp_hourly_stats),
t8 as (SELECT @tc := SUM(total_count) as total_day_count from temp_hourly_stats),
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ispeed_count,t3.rlvd_count,t4.stopline_count,t5.wrong_dir_count,t6.wrong_lane_count,t7.zebra_cross_count,t8.total_day_count
FROM t1,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8 limit 1;
END
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I want to put data from one table to another using postgresql function?*

Comment: SQL functions don't use BEGIN and END.  Remove those two lines.

Comment: Sir, now its showing this error

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
LINE 11: t8 as (SELECT @tc := SUM(total_count) as total_day_count fro...

Comment: Is my syntax wrong??

Comment: `SELECT @tc := SUM(total_count)`  is invalid standard SQL and invalid in Postgres - what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Yes that's why I said that I am not completely fine with the syntax of postgreSql by the way thanks for the help

Comment: Well, that expression isn't even remotely valid standard SQL either, so this has nothing to do with Postgres specific syntax

Comment: Yeah i know that thats why I asked what is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt to translate your function to correct code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function dailyyyy_volation_routine(
   _ispeed_count integer,
   _rlvd_count integer,
   _stopline_count integer,
   _wrongdir_count integer,
   _wronglane_count integer,
   _zebracross_count integer,
_total_count integer) RETURNS void AS
$$INSERT INTO temp_daily_stats(
   ispeed_count,
   rlvd_count,
   stopline_count,
   wrongdir_count,
   wronglane_count,
   zebracross_count,
   total_count
)
SELECT SUM(ispeed_count),
       SUM(rlvd_count),
       SUM(stop_line_count),
       SUM(wrong_dir_count),
       SUM(wrong_lane_count),
       SUM(zebra_cross_count),
       SUM(total_count)
FROM temp_hourly_stats$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE Function dailyyyy_volation_routine(ispeed_count integer)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO temp_daily_stats(ispeed_count)
 SELECT SUM(ispeed_count) as ispeed_count from temp_hourly_stats;
END
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;

Comment: I did the same but its saying syntax error near Insert or at insert

Comment: I am using latest version of postgre

Comment: Ah-hah, but you never said in your answer that the function has a parameter of the same name (which is bad practice). In that case, you have to qualify the column. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Oh sorry sir I ll try this one

Comment: Sorry but its still showing "syntax error at or near INSERT"

Comment: Hm. The code in your question is so far removed from actual SQL that I cannot even start guessing what you are trying to do...

Comment: Actually i want to put sum of data from one table to another table as you can see in my question but the condition is that I want to do it with stored function as the latest version of postgresql does not support stored procedure

Comment: And if I talk about other database like mssql, mysql, mariadb , than I implemented it on that but in case of postgre I am a little bit confused because many things changed in latest version which is postgresql version 12

Comment: I think sir now you understand what I am trying to ask

Comment: I doubt that that is valid SQL anywhere. Anyway, I have attempted to translate your code into valid SQL in my answer.

Comment: It worked thanks ,but yes in my question I specified that may be the way I am using syntax is wrong because the same query worked in mariadb

Comment: Well, MariaDB is entirely different software. And even if that code worked there, it will still scan the same table seven times, which is horribly inefficient.

Comment: I implemented same query on different databases by applying different methods but in case of postgresql I was not sure that's why I asked